# Check version of opensips

Tags: switching, opensips

I'm trying to check the version of opensips on a soft switch, and the below are not yielding the results I need. How do I check what version of opensips is running?

```
opensips -v
opensips -version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenSIPS binary also has a version option. Just run:

```
opensips -V
```

To list all options, use the help argument:

```
opensips -h
```

Answer (score 1):

```
opensipsctl fifo version
```

Should show something like this....

```
Server:: OpenSIPS (1.7.2-tls (x86_64/linux))
```

Answer (score 0):

Any software you can use xxx -h to find the command and almost "-v" is the command to check the version